# split number with some conditionally in javascript

Tags: javascript

My values are like below:

```
version 5500
version 5501
version 5560
version 5563
```

and I want output like:

```
5500 => 55.0
5501 => 55.0.1
5560 => 55.6
5563 => 55.6.3
```

If fourth digit is more than ZERO it means I want to split with 2 decimal points. 5501 => 55.0.1 and 5500 => 55.0

I tried this:

```js
function versionssd(amount) {
  var divisor = Number(amount) > 999 ? 100 : 10;
  var value = amount / divisor;
  document.write(Number.isInteger(value)+"==="+value.toFixed(1)+"==="+value);
  return Number.isInteger(value) ? value.toFixed(1) : value;
}

versionssd(1101)
```

Comment: There's only limited use for `document.write`. In this case a `console.log()` would be the proper tool to use.

Comment: Convert `amount` into a string (if it isn't already one), split it into single numbers (or use a regex to get the parts) and then rebuild the string from it.

Comment: `.match(/version (\d\d)(\d)(\d)/) |> (([, p, s, m]) => \`${p}.${s}${m > 0 ? \`.${m}\` : ""}\`)`

Answer (score 1):

You can call reduce-right on the indices and splice in the dots

Afterwards, you can remove the trailing zeroes.

**Edit:** I added a minimum dot parameter to impose a minimum requirement of dots to be present, if the remaining values are zero.

```js
const main = () => {
  let versions = [ 5000, 5500, 5501, 5560, 5563 ];
  let points = [ 2, 3 ];
  
  console.log(versions.map(version => cleanZeros(formatVersionNumber(version, points), 1)));
}

const splice = (str, val, pos) => [str.slice(0, pos), val, str.slice(pos)].join('');

const formatVersionNumber = (version, points) => {
  return points.reduceRight((res, point) => splice(res, '.', point), '' + version)
}

const cleanZeros = (str, min) => {
  while ((str.match(/\./g) || []).length > min && str.match(/\.0$/)) {
    str = str.replace(/\.0$/, ''); // Remove trailing zeroes
  }
  return str;
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `\.(.)(.+)`

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/rIlHvQ/1

```js
function versionss(amount) {
  var divisor = Number(amount) > 999 ? 100 : 10;
  var value = amount / divisor;
  return Number.isInteger(value) 
    ? value.toFixed(1) 
    : value.toString().replace(/\.(.)(.+)/, '.$1.$2');
}

console.log(versionss(5500));
console.log(versionss(5501));
console.log(versionss(5560));
console.log(versionss(5563));
```